Surrogacy and forbidden relationships
What is the law if a woman is a surrogate for her sibling's fertilized egg? I.e. a sister is implanted with the blastocysts of her brother and sister in law. According to the halacha, the child is hers, at least in part, so would that child be a mamzer, given that the father is her brother? If so, I assume it would therefore be forbidden, but by what precedent would it be forbidden? If not, or in any case, I would like to see some discussion on this in the poskim if possible, to see the reasoning behind everything regarding this interesting topic.
